# Pop-up/modal dilemma

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm stuck in a problem that on first glance seems simple, but actually it's a bit hard to fix. I have a share button on my `colorbox` and when a user clicks it I want to open a pop-up with the social media link. Now I tried a few simple pop-ups but a lot of the blockers are disabling them and it's not an option to force the users to disable their software.

Can anyone offer suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace your popup with iframe integrated into your page. Place it to the center of the page, hide it initially. And on user click set iframe's src to the url which you open in popup now and show iframe.

Comment: Not a real option, too many images and that means the user generating a ton of requests to social media websites.

Comment: With popup you open the same url with the same count of images.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest some sort of modal, jqModal is pretty popular and my preferred way of doing things. Do you have any code that you could share?

Comment: I thought about modal, but for example Chrome doesn't like cross-domain requests. Plus when a user click on the image, there's already 1 modal window (colorbox), more than one modal makes unpredictable results in browsers.

Comment: I would recommend against making cross domain requests, there's a reason why browsers don't like it. But if you absolutely must, the only way I could think of is using creating a layer function. That way you could add as many layers on top of your existing html. FYI jqMOdal does allow for iframe content.